# Haml: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In my project, I am using `haml` to code the views, and in this partial, server shows `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input` error:

```
.col-xs-12#new_posts_form 
  %h2= "New posts"
  = form_tag admin_articles_posts_path
    - @posts.each_with_index do |post,i|
      = fields_for "posts[#{i}]", post do |f| 
        .col-xs-12
          %label Content
          = f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content", class: "form-control"
        .col-xs-12
          %label Publishing date
          =f.date_field :start_date, placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd", class: "form-control"
        .col-xs-12
          = f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-default"
```

the error points line 13, the last one.

Comment: i think "do" is missing  = form_tag admin_articles_posts_path

Comment: Yes, that is it! can you write an answer in order to choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think correct syntax is

```
= form_tag admin_articles_posts_path do
```